# Unable to add keyCredentials value to Azure App manifest

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, azureadapps

I used the instructions from [Performing app-only operations on SharePoint Online through Azure AD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/05/03/performing-app-only-operations-on-sharepoint-online-through-azure-ad/),when I had to modify the app manifest to :

```
>   "keyCredentials": [
>     {
>       "customKeyIdentifier": "<mybase64CertHash>",
>       "keyId": "<myKeyId>",
>       "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
>       "usage": "Verify",
>       "value":  "<mybase64Cert>"
>      }   ],
```

I didn't get any errors upon upload, but when I download the manifest I saw that  keyCredentials value was null:
[image]

I tried to readd to the manifest the required value "MIIDPjCCAiqgAwIBAgIQ3td...KFgcGi" but this caused to error:

```
Failed to save manifest.Error details: KeyValueMustBeNull
```

I tried to modify one character in keyId and save but got following error:

```
Error converting value <MyOriginalKey> to type 'System.Guid'
```

How to store the value that i need in keyCredentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a ticket to MS and their answer was that this value is stored in their DB but **for security reasons is not shown in Manifest**. The same would be for password for example.
Since the CSOM calls (original purpose of the app) work seems like the answer I recieved is correct.